# Find the CSS to modify the highlight of a tabPanel with cicerone

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm using the package [`{cicerone}`](https://github.com/JohnCoene/cicerone) to create a tour on my shiny app. The problem is that the highlight is completely opaque when the navbar is `fixed-top`. I searched during hours how to modify the CSS so that the result is the same as when the navbar is `static` but without success. I asked to the package maintainer but no solution so far.

**Navbar with good display:**

```
library(shiny)
library(cicerone)

home_guide <- Cicerone$
  new(id = "homeGuide")$
  step(
    "[data-value='home']",
    "Hello",
    "Hello from tab 1",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='tab']",
    "Text",
    "This is an input",
    is_id = FALSE
  )

ui <- navbarPage(
  "cicerone",
  header = list(use_cicerone()),
  id = "nav",
  # position = "fixed-top",
  tabPanel(
    "home",
    h1("First tab", id = "home_primary"),
    textInput("home_secondary", "Text")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "tab",
    h1("Second tab", id = "tab_primary"),
    textInput("tab_secondary", "Text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  home_guide$init()$start()
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Navbar with bad display (add `position = "fixed-top"` in the `ui`):**

```
library(shiny)
library(cicerone)

home_guide <- Cicerone$
  new(id = "homeGuide")$
  step(
    "[data-value='home']",
    "Hello",
    "Hello from tab 1",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='tab']",
    "Text",
    "This is an input",
    is_id = FALSE
  )

ui <- navbarPage(
  "cicerone",
  header = list(use_cicerone()),
  id = "nav",
  position = "fixed-top",
  tabPanel(
    "home",
    h1("First tab", id = "home_primary"),
    textInput("home_secondary", "Text")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "tab",
    h1("Second tab", id = "tab_primary"),
    textInput("tab_secondary", "Text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  home_guide$init()$start()
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there an expert in CSS willing to show me how to modify the CSS in the second case so that the result is the same as in the first one? This person can also make a pull request to implement his/her solution in the package.

*Note: for now (12 October 2020), you probably need to install the development version of `{cicerone}` (`devtools::install_github("JohnCoene/cicerone")`).*

Comment: I am using the CRAN version and your problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS solves the problem (it comes from [this comment](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/driver.js/issues/133#issuecomment-549714982) on the `driver.js` repo):

```
div#driver-highlighted-element-stage, div#driver-page-overlay {
  background: transparent !important;
  outline: 5000px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .75)
}
```

It is now incorporated in the development version of `{cicerone}` (to be installed with: `devtools::install_github("JohnCoene/cicerone")`).

Answer (score 2):

the error is caused by making the `position: fixed;` and looking at the fact that the navbar is the top most element i.e child of the body, and that `position : absolute;` fixes this on way would be to modify the css

```css
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom{
    position : absolute;
}
```

However this invalidates the effect of `position : fixed;`. So a way to do this is by listening for user clicks on the `next|previous` buttons, to toggle between position fixed and position absolute, this can be done using `js` and to run js from shiny we need the `shinyjs` package.

```r
install.packages("shinyjs")
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(cicerone)

homeGuide <- Cicerone$
  new(id = "homeGuide")$
  step(
    "[data-value='home']",
    "Hello",
    "Hello from tab 1",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='tab']",
    "Tab :(",
    "This is a tab",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "[data-value='last']",
    "Last",
    "This is the last tab the one we check for",
    is_id = FALSE
  )$
  step(
    "home_secondary",
    "Text",
    "This is an input"
  )
```

#### the UI

- call `useShinyjs` to import shinyjs javascript libs into the webpage.
- the next line sets the style by default to position absolute.

```r
ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom{
        position : absolute;
      }
  "))),
  navbarPage(
  "cicerone",
  header = list(use_cicerone()),
  id = "nav",
   position = "fixed-top",
  tabPanel(
    "home",
    h1("First tab", id = "home_primary"),
    textInput("home_secondary", "Text")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "tab",
    h1("Second tab", id = "tab_primary"),
    textInput("tab_secondary", "Text")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "last",
    h1("last tab", id = "tab_last"),
    textInput("inp_text", "Text")
  )
))
```

## Server :

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  homeGuide$init()$start()
  # if the user clicks the next button
  observeEvent(input$homeGuide_cicerone_next, {
    # check if the last highlighted element is the last tab
    if(grepl("last",input$homeGuide_cicerone_next$highlighted) ) runjs("document.querySelector('.navbar').style.position = 'fixed'; document.querySelector('.navbar').style.position") 
# because of some weird glitch you need to call the value of document.querySelector('.navbar').style.position in order for it to be changed took me a day to figure this out
   })
  # now for the previous button
  observeEvent(input$homeGuide_cicerone_previous, {
    # check if the before previous element is the last tab
    # i don't know if this is the way it should behave but apparently shiny is called before the click is sent to js and before previous actually contains the value of the previous element
      if(grepl("last",input$homeGuide_cicerone_previous$before_previous) ) runjs("document.querySelector('.navbar').style.position = 'absolute'; document.querySelector('.navbar').style.position")
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Note : that changing the `z-index` above `100002` will push the element above the gray overlay.

Comment: Doing this, you're "cancelling" the line `position = "fixed-top"` in the `ui`, but not solving the problem. This solution is the same thing as removing this line, meaning that if I have a long page and scroll down, the navbar will disappear instead of being constantly displayed at the top of the screen during the scrolling. I'm looking for a way to keep the navbar everytime, even when scrolling down, and to remove the "opacity" of the tour highlighted elements.

Comment: Using `sticky` instead of `absolute` does not solve the problem as the tour is still completely opaque

Comment: I think the only way to solve this issue is by changing the position type on load and then when `cicerone` is done @bretauv

Comment: I think the problem is due to the z-index because the elements overlay in the wrong order, so I still think there is a more global solution

Comment: @bretauv you do have more steps in your real program?

Comment: Yes I have more than 2

Comment: @bretauv I implemented the method I suggested. the hard part was getting the change to the style of the navbar to be acknowledged the workaround I found is by basically "printing" its value

Comment: @bretauv we could drop the `htmlwidgets::JS` call

Comment: I'm really having a hard time implementing this in my actual app (though your example works) so I upvote it but I still hope someone will come with a simpler solution (a simple CSS glitch). The thing is I really don't understand why having a fixed or absolute navbar changes so much the behavior of other elements...

Comment: I v gone through the `driver.js` repo. I couldn't pinpoint the issue. can you add the issue you're facing to the question

Comment: I can't add what the issue I'm facing right now but I will try to update my post. In case it helps, [this](https://github.com/JohnCoene/cicerone/issues/10) is the issue on `{cicerone}` repo, and [this](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/driver.js/issues/95#issuecomment-586357803) is the issue on the `driver.js` repo.

Comment: I think this is the solution: https://github.com/JohnCoene/cicerone/issues/10#issuecomment-709565384. I'll wait until the fix is confirmed and included in the package before putting it as a solution. Thanks for your help and your time anyway!